# background align top right not working

Tags: css, alignment

On my site http://goo.gl/16XdA on page "about us" I'm trying to align the norway map on the top right of the div but does not seems to be working (as you can see it only shows a small part of the map and on the left side). What is wrong with my CSS code? Thanks

```
#activity {
    height: 1300px;
    background: #8aba56;
    padding-top: 150px;
    background: url(../images/bg-water22.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#activity-container {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font: 12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding:25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px dotted #666;
    background: #fff url(../images/norway-map.png) no-repeat right top;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=93)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=93);
    opacity: 0.93; /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image has too much negative space to align with the div. Crop the image or specify the background-position to the pixel. In essence, there's nothing wrong with your CSS. The image is just too big.

As you can see, there's a lot of white space to the right of the map:
http://purewords.com/test4/images/norway-map.png

Comment: got it... I think i did not save the "small" version of the picture. Thanks!